# Library/api for word correction

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to find some tips to do word corection, but not using auto-correct (which is hilarious). What I'm trying to do is this: if someone types a word in text box and it's incorrect then after the word the app puts the '?' sign.

Even more, if it's a bad typed word, if i press it, i want to show a few suggestions such as similary words!

Answer (score 0):

This approach is fairly dumbed down, but what you could do would be to store the dictionary in a list. Assuming that you have a certain range of words to choose from, you could maybe use LINQ to get all the words in the dictionary whose length is `+/-` 2 characters from the word you have.

Once that you have that list, you could use [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to see how *far* are the word in the dictionary and the word you have. The smaller the distance, the closer the words are. You could sort descending by distance to get the *best match*.

Comment: OK, that should keep me busy for a while. It's an interasting idea, I'm going to try to implement this... Thanks!

Comment: @FlaviusIbanescu: This was something I implemented as an assignment some years back. I stored a dictionary in a set and used that set to see if a word exists. If not, then I did something similar to the above. Alternatively, you could give [this](http://blog.faroo.com/2012/06/24/1000x-faster-spelling-correction-source-code-released/) site a look.

Comment: OK, but make me understand something. The dictionary is a list you've created, right? I want to use all words in english dictionary, how can I do that?
BTW: i checked that link, it's awesome!

Comment: The dictionary I mention in my answer is something I would create myself, with a `<incorrect_word, list_of_potential_words>` structure. The set is something you construct out of data you hopefully already have. Take a look [here](http://www.curlewcommunications.co.uk/wordlist.html) or [here](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) for a list of words in the English dictionary.